# Pointer Subtraction in C with an array

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

If I have the following lines of code, why is b-a = 2?

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
int *b = &(a[2]);
```

Comment: Because `&a[2]` is the same as `a+2` and `a+2 = b`

Comment: The question is unclear to me because... well.... the answer seems so obviously what Eugene commented. Please explain what makes you wonder. Maybe because `sizeof(int)!=1`?

Comment: `&(a[2]) == &(*(a + 2)) == a + 2` So `a + 2 - a == 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate slightly on Eugene's answer, `a` is a pointer to the beginning of the array, and `a[2]` is the same as `*(a+2)`.

So you could say that the `&` "cancels" the `*` as you dereference the pointer and then look at the address of the element that it points to. So `*b = &(a[2]) = &(*(a+2)) = a+2`.
Therefore `b-a=2`